# Button click not working. - Android

Tags: java, android, xml

When I click my button in emulator, my application crashes.

Below is my layout.xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:onClick="loginUser"
    android:text="@string/login_text" />
```

Here is my method loginUser() in my MainActivity.java:

```
public void loginUser() {
    Log.d("User Authentication Service", "Trying to login...");
    doLogin(new Intent(getBaseContext(), LoginUserService.class));
}
```

I've defined which method should be called in my layout.xml using the below line:

```
   android:onClick="loginUser"
```

But when I press the button in emulator, application crashes. I've tried changing the above value in layout.xml as show below:

```
   android:onClick="loginUser()"
```

But nothing works. What's is wrong?

Comment: your method signature is wrong

Comment: The debugging messages in your logcat might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the parameter `View` in your method signature.

Try changing your code as shown below:

```
public void loginUser(View view) {
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:**

And it should be `android:onClick="loginUser"` in your `layout.xml`.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html